# Почему я получаю ошибку "Type ... is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? number : boolean'"

Tags: typescript

```
async function sub<T extends string | string[] = string>(
  uid: T,
): Promise<T extends string ? number : boolean> {
  if (Array.isArray(uid)) {
    // Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? number : boolean'.
    return true;
  }

  // Type '1' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? number : boolean'.
  return 1;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIxAgRgHgBUYBTAD2RIgBMRtkAnVCAcxgB96nWBtAXRgBeLsxYA%20ABQJU1AFwxCASnkAFBugC2qECXwAoGIYWkKVWiNYwA-DAgINuEgxjzc6dABsSwCHrEwAbwMjVDgYCQBBBgZgMAA6bSiYsCkZRUVA4KMjBhJkBAYsRgQSAG4smABfCtz8wpgARnLKoA)

Comment: Вроде для случая когда тип результата зависит от типа параметров есть перегрузка функций

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAIwDwBVEFMAeUuYAJsilAE4xgDmAfABQgwkBciWAlB2CALZpclANwAoUJFgIU6bHkLEyFanQDaAXSYt2nHojRw4AG1wBDMOInho8JKkw4CRUuWRUatRAB8VnzYgAvH502qwc3LwCQpQ+BkamFogA3mKI6YgwwIiMAIKUlGYAngB0MMj5hUXMrFxcKWkZTZS4UCCUSFQguOJNAL6N6S1tHYgAjOIDYqZQiEjBDowA5O6US1ziMwZBsmiMaktmBUsaG0A

Comment: @AlexeyTen я помню про перегрузку и использую её. история с вопросом такая: на кодревью коллеги я увидел что-то вроде [такого](https://pastebin.com/WWUuR62J), решил что уже можно разруливать возвращаемое значение на conditional type и написал свой код. typescript заругался и я, предположив что где-то ошибся, пульнул сюда вопрос перед сном. а сегодня, после ответа и комментариев, увидел, что `sub2`, из реального кода, просто возвращает неявный any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько мне известно это архитектурное ограничение в typescript. Лично для меня оно не логичное, но что имеем то имеем.

Посмотрите на примеры ниже. Они проще, чем тот с которым вы столкнулись, но в них та же проблема.

```js
function test1 <T extends string> (val: T): T extends string ? string : boolean {
  if (typeof val === "string") {
    // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : boolean'
    return "qwerty";
  }
  // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string : boolean'
  return true;
}
```

В функции test1 переменная val сужается к T & string. А вот тип возвращаемого значения не просто string или boolean, у него получается зависимость от T. В этом случаи компилятор должен был бы обработать все возможные return и слепить их в один тим, а потом сравнить с типом указанным в описании функции. Только после этого компилятор мог бы правильно проверить возвращаемый тип.

Тайп чекер просто не обрабатывает таких случаев на данный момент.

Вот еще два примера, которые в лоб возвращают нужное значение, но компилятор ругается на них:

```js
function test2<T extends string>(val: T): T extends string ? T : T {.
   // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? T : T'
   return val;
}

function test3<T>(val: T): T extends T ? T : T {
    // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T extends T ? T : T'
    return val;
}
```

Дополнительно можете посмотреть эти два тикета на гите. Они оба закрыты с пометкой Design Limitation. И похоже, что это не логичное поведение так и останется навсегда.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22735

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929

В этих тикетах разработчики typescript рекомендуют явно указать тип с помощью as.